# Track element in a dictionary with python

Tags: python, dictionary

Given the a and b:

```
a  =  ['0', '4', '6']

b = {"0": 2, "1": 2, "2": 2,"4": 3, "5": 3, "6": 3,"29": 1, "30": 1, "31": 1, "32": 1, "33": 1}
```

(Keys are nodes and values are modules or community in a network)

I need to count on how many communities the elements of `a` are in the network by using python. For example, in `b` with have 3 communities (1, 2, 3) where 4 and 6 are in community 3 and 0 is in community 2 so in total with have 2 communities involved (this is the number I am looking for)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show case you're attempts.

Comment: I don't have any valuable code so far. :(

Comment: Yes, we want to see your ‘useless’ code because that will tell us where you have got to so far.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: `import operator; stuff = operator.itemgetter(*a); number = len(set(stuff(b)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres one way to do it by using a for loop to check each element of b. HOWEVER, please show attempts of what you're trying to do, it's much better for discussion of what you want instead of just taking solutions from others

```
a  =  ['0', '4', '6']

b = {"0": 2, "1": 2, "2": 2,"4": 3, "5": 3, "6": 3,"29": 1, "30": 1, "31": 1, "32": 1, "33": 1}

allcommunities = []
for x in b:
    if x in a:
        if b[x] not in allcommunities:
            allcommunities.append(b[x])

print(len(allcommunities))
```

Comment: I think, we need to call len(allcommunities) without print otherwise we'll get an error

Comment: Sorry, no I just forgot a parenthesis. Thanks for pointing that out, just edited my response

Answer (score 1):

```
a  =  ['0', '4', '6']

b = {"0": 2, "1": 2, "2": 2,"4": 3, "5": 3, "6": 3,"29": 1, "30": 1, "31": 1, "32": 1, "33": 1}

d = []

c = 0

for i in a:
    for e in b:
        if e == i:
            if b[e] not in (d):
                c += 1
                d.append(b[e])

print(c)
```

Comment: @ktoto, Welcome to SO.. please avoid answering question which show no attempt in future.

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad.

Comment: Sorry, I did not have anything that could help to find this code. I was quite far of getting this result. Sorry and thanks once again @ktoto :)